# VLOOKUP with Dropdown List

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have two spreadsheets where the first spreadsheet is a table (T_EBAY_LIST) and the second spreadsheet is a detail of the item from the first.

I am trying to retrieve the **item-code** depending on which **title** (which is all the titles in the table) is selected from a dropdown list found on my second sheet to fill in the details of that item.

I have tried using VLOOKUP in several ways and other search functions but it always gives me an error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since your title is in the middle of your data (rather than in the first column) a `VLOOKUP` is unsuitable. Look into `INDEX` and `MATCH` together

Comment: @CallumDA You think you could give me a hand. Im trying with what you said but im having no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your provided sample data, in your "Ebay Item Detailed" sheet in cell B5 and copied down, use this formula to get the desired results:

```
=IF($B$3="","",INDEX(T_EBAY_LIST[#All],MATCH($B$3,T_EBAY_LIST[[#All],[Title]],0),MATCH($A5,T_EBAY_LIST[#Headers],0)))
```